# Is this correct to reassign already intialized variable?

Tags: java

I am reading hadoop source code , Here I have a doubt "org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils" they reassigned a list which is already intiailized.

```
  public static Collection<String> getStringCollection(String str){
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (str == null)
      return values;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer (str,",");
    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      values.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    return values;
  }
```

Is there any reason to reassign here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not your own written code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a useless reassignment.  It must be some refactoring gone wrong.  At worst, it will cause a tiny performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, but it will cause a tiny performance hit! and they should use String.split() instead of StringTokenizer.